# Render Texture is black on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using render texture to play videos. It works well on editor window but when I make a build for android, the render texture is just black. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the video on the device?

Comment: it is attached in the project itself. It creates black border when it plays the video on android.

Comment: Check the color format on that RenderTexture, some formats don't play well with android